# setRepresentedFilename for electron app not working

Tags: macos, electron

I'm trying to use the setRepresentedFilename option for my app's browserwindow, but it doesn't seem to do anything.

I don't get errors, and any path (resolved or hard-coded) does not change the titlebar to the file's name.

```
app.on('open-file', function(ev, path) {
    win.setRepresentedFilename( path );
});
```

The app is packaged for Mac, so unless macOS versions is involved in some way, I'm not sure why it's not working.

Am I missing something here? The docs for this is not in-depth and provides only a basic example that apparently 'works'.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems it was an order of operations problem, the set command should be executed when the app has finished loading. For example:

```
win.webContents.on('did-finish-load', function() {
    win.setRepresentedFilename( filePath );
});
```

The above should work. You'll have to handle it such that you have the url to pass. You can use ipcMain and such.